# How to set the value into 0 when there's no input and seperate data based on date in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how to segregate the data and display the `PRN` children based on the `date` for example `january` then if there's a data which is `machine 1` then have `assetCode: PRN` it will display on the children header and then it will display the value if there's another `machine 2` then have `assetCode: PRN1` it will added on `january` children. then if the `machine 1` have no `assetCode: PRN1` then it will set at `0`, same as `machine 2`

here's the code:

***list.component.ts***

```
rowData = [
{
      code: "Machine 1",
      assetCode: "PRN",
      assetCount: 1,
      date: "2019-01-18 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 1",
      assetCode: "PRN",
      assetCount: 1,
      date: "2019-01-19 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 2",
      assetCode: "PRN 1",
      assetCount: 3,
      date: "2019-01-20 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 3",
      assetCode: "PRN",
      assetCount: 1,
      date: "2019-01-21 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 4",
      assetCode: "PRN 1",
      assetCount: 3,
      date: "2019-01-22 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      code: "Machine 5",
      assetCode: "PRN 1",
      assetCount: 3,
      date: "2019-01-23 00:00:00"
    }
];
this.columnDefs.push(
      {
        'headerName': 'Style/Machine',
        'field': 'code',
        'pinned': 'left',
        'lockPosition': true
      }
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

      const record = {
        'headerName': this.monthNames[i].monthName,
        'children': [
          {
            'headerName': 'Total',
            'columnGroupShow': 'closed'
             'field': 'total'
          }
        ]
      };

record.children.push(
          {
            'headerName': 'PRN',
            'columnGroupShow': 'open'
             'field': 'assetCount'
          }
);
this.columnDefs.push(record);
}
```

How to make it like this.

[image]

Example in January there's only 3 machine which is Machine 1, Machine 1 and Machine 2
in February only 1 machine which is machine 5.

Machine 1 have assetCode which is the PRN and have total assetCount 4, which is the first machine have assetCount 3 and the second machine have assetCount 1 the total assetCount is 4.

Comment: its difficult to understand where are you facing issue, did you try to do it by yourself if yes please provide stalkbliz link, so that I can understand where are you facing issue.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-pvtbsw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @piyushjain here's the stackblitz i made

Comment: can you please check again you json ? I am seeing all machines in January only.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-vg7rjs?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thats may second options.

but here's the latest update https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-pvtbsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-grid-options.json

Comment: you can check it now @piyushjain